# How to make a sure loss contract?

Tags: probability, logic

I found this question from Ian Hacking's [book on probability and induction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521775019).

> Epicurus is an optimist. He thinks the Leafs will come in first in
>   their league next year ($T$).
>
> His betting rate on $T$ is $0.7$. His betting
>   rate on $\sim\! T$ is $0.2$.
>
> Make a sure-loss contract against Epicurus.

I've googled it, and it seems a sure-loss contract is one wherein Epicurus would lose every time. The question is asking us to make one, so does that imply I have to set a price point for $T$ and $\sim\! T$?

If so, am I just supposed to set them at $(0.7 + n) \cdot x$ and $(0.2 - n) \cdot x$?